# Twitter "Profile editing is currently unavailable" for days

Tags: twitter

For the last  15 days I have receive thed following error whenever I try to edit my Twitter profile:

[image: Twitter - Profile editing is currently unavailable.]

> Profile editing is currently unavailable.

At first I thought it was just Twitter maintenance, but I still receive the same message after hours and even days.

Could it be because I am a new user, or because I use Twitter's "new profile"?
Any trick to avoid that and get the ability to edit my yet-empty profile bio?

Google shows 20 people asking the same question, some of them as soon as September 2013.

Comment: @pnuts: I have several accounts for different products.

Comment: @pnuts it shouldn't have anything to do with being a new user, editing the profile is part of having an account and isn't restricted to how long you've had a Twitter account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do 'edit profile' from your profile page. Try going to Settings -> Edit Profile and make changes from there.